# Use hardware search button

Tags: search, windows-phone-7

I have experience with Android's search functionality as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html, but haven't been able to find anything similar for windows phone 7.

Alternatively, what is the best approach to provide search functionality within your windows phone application?

The search scope is within the application itself, and while it is obviously possible to implement it myself, I'm looking for something that follows the ui guidelines of windows phone 7, and possibly also an interface to provide search results from the app, even when the search button is pressed while the app is in the background.

Comment: What is the scope of your search?  Specific on-device items like contacts, everything on the device, or web-enabled searching?  It makes a huge difference to the potential answers.

Comment: I've updated the question, it is just within the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fully responsible for handling search within your app. There are no WP7 specific guidelines or tools available. Do what's best within the context of your app.

You cannot integrate with the built in search facility to include app specific results with anything returned as part of a bing search.

Answer (score 0):

To add, interface to Windows Phone 7 hardware search button is not exposed to third party developers. You need to provide your own search button in the application and handle it appropriately.